# ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator()) give an error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, cartopy, map-projections

I have the following program:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

birddata = pd.read_csv("bird_tracking.csv")
bird_names = pd.unique(birddata.bird_name)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10)
ax = plt.axis(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
ax.set_extent((-25.0,20.0,52.0,10.0))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS,linestyle=":")

for name in bird_names:
    ix = birddata['bird_name'] == name
    x, y = birddata.longitude[ix], birddata.latitude[ix]
    ax.plot(x, y,".", transform = ccrs.Geodetic(), label = name)

plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.savefig("map.pdf")
```

I am using Spyder 5 and python 3.9. But I have an invalid syntax for the line  `ax = plt.axis(projection=ccrs.Mercator())`
If I run the program, I receive this message in the console:
[error in ax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3HpZ.jpg)

I am unable to find help on this. Moreover, if you go to this [link](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html?highlight=ax%20plot), you will see that they use it exactly as I do. So what am I missing?

Thank you i advance for your help.

Comment: The line before the error line is missing a closing parenthesis `)`. It should be: `plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))`

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler  Thank you, that fix my ax problem. But it have another problem, it seems that the same line don't like the projection argument. I receive this error message: «  axis() got an unexpected keyword argument 'projection' ». And so the plot is empty. Any idea?